# Asterisk SIP - Dial in parallel

Tags: asterisk, sip, asterisk-java

I've searched the documentations of asterisk and could not find any info of the limit of parallel destinations when dialing in parallel.

```
exten => n,Dial(number1&number2&number3&...],other-options)
```

Does anyone know what is the limitation in the ideal case, when there are no other active call sessions etc?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are no limits, except

1) Dialplan line is limited to something like 200chars.

2) load limited by your server max load. Usually limited by CPS, becuase it give alot of inivites and cpu spike. Something like 50/sec for modern servers, so near 50-100.

In general if you need call multiple people(like 30+) much better use queue, becuase they do redial in same session.